# Select unique values as columns and count or their matches each unique value of a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with four columns: `Id` , `Name`, `CampaignId`, `Type`.

Here is a sample:

```
+----+-----------+------------+------+
| Id |   NAME    | CampaignId | Type |
+----+-----------+------------+------+
|  1 | Campaign1 |         10 |    0 |
|  2 | Campaign2 |         11 |    0 |
|  3 | Campaign2 |         11 |    1 |
|  4 | Campaign2 |         11 |    2 |
|  5 | Campaign2 |         11 |    3 |
|  6 | Campaign3 |         12 |    1 |
|  7 | Campaign3 |         12 |    2 |
|  8 | Campaign3 |         12 |    2 |
|  9 | Campaign3 |         12 |    2 |
| 10 | Campaign4 |         13 |    0 |
| 11 | Campaign4 |         13 |    2 |
+----+-----------+------------+------+
```

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TMP;
CREATE TABLE #TMP (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY ,
    [NAME] NVARCHAR(20),
    [CampaignId] INT,
    [Type] INT
);

INSERT INTO #TMP ([Name], [CampaignId], [Type]) VALUES 
('Campaign1', 10, 0),
('Campaign2', 11, 0),
('Campaign2', 11, 1),
('Campaign2', 11, 2),
('Campaign2', 11, 3),
('Campaign3', 12, 1),
('Campaign3', 12, 2),
('Campaign3', 12, 2),
('Campaign3', 12, 2),
('Campaign4', 13, 0),
('Campaign4', 13, 2)

SELECT * FROM #TMP
```

I need a query to create a new table that will output a row that contains the `Name`, `CampaignId` and columns for each unique value in `Type` with its corresponding count for each unique `CampaignId`.

I don't know the exact number and possible values in `Type` column. It could be vary.

Expected result for sample dataset is a table

```
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   Name    | CampaignId | Type0 | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Campaign1 |         10 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
| Campaign2 |         11 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
| Campaign3 |         12 |     0 |     1 |     3 |     0 |
| Campaign4 |         13 |     1 |     0 |     1 |     0 |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Are you limited to Types 0-3, or could there be (a lot?) more? Could it vary?

Comment: I dont know the exact number of different types. It could be vary.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional agregation

```
selecr name,CampaignId,sum(case when  type =0 then 1 else 0 end) as type0,
sum(case when  type =1 then 1 else 0 end) as type1,
sum(case when  type =2 then 1 else 0 end) as type2,
sum(case when  type =3 then 1 else 0 end) as type3 from #TMP
group by name,CampaignId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name,
       campaignid,
       Type0=sum(case when type= 0 then 1 else 0 END ) ,
       Type1=sum(case when type= 1 then 1 else 0 END ) ,
       Type2=sum(case when type= 2 then 1 else 0 END ) ,
       Type3=sum(case when type= 3 then 1 else 0 END ) 
       FROM #TMP
       group by name,campaignid
```